# Error "PHP Error wasArray to string conversion"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I create a project using codeigniter now. But, I got an error message "PHP Error wasArray to string conversion". What's wrong? Thanks before...

[image]

This is my controller:

```
public function index($page = 'dashboard') {
    $data['num_rows'] = $this->admin_produk_model->count_product();

    $this->load->view('admin/templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/templates/sidebar', $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/pages/' . $page, $data);
    $this->load->view('admin/templates/footer', $data);

}
```

My model:

```
public function count_product() {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('produk');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->num_rows();
}
```

My view:

```
<span class="info-box-number"><?php echo ['num_rows'];?></span>
```

Comment: `['num_rows']` is an array. You should be using the set view variable. In this case, it's probably `$num_rows`.

Comment: In view `$data['num_rows']` become $num_row. But it is array too according to your model

Answer (score 1):

`$q->num_rows()` in you model returns an object and You are Passing that object to view correctly, now you can simply use `$num_rows` in your view file to show it.

```
<span class="info-box-number"><?php echo $num_rows;?></span>
```

or

```
<span class="info-box-number"><?=$num_rows;?></span>
```

Comment: I agree with this answer. The problem is in your view. You are passing the information correctly from model to controller to view, but you are not using the right syntax in your view.

Answer (score 0):

When you send the datas in CodeIgniter using `$data` variable, you can directly access the datas using the keyname as variable name i.e

```
 $data['num_rows'] = $this->admin_produk_model->count_product();
```

Then in your view page access it like `$num_rows`.

You are getting that error because you are trying to `echo` an array.
You have to use `print_r()` function to print it

So Instead of this

```
 <span class="info-box-number"><?php echo ['num_rows'];?></span>
```

Do this

```
 <span class="info-box-number"><?php print_r($num_rows);?></span>
```

Comment: they can also use `echo $num_rows` , `print_r` is not necessary.